# How to fill select box to jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable

I am using jquery datatable and angularJS.

I have the table

```
table#reception_issues.table.display(cellspacing='0', width='100%')
thead
tr
    th #
    th Date
    th Issue
    th Author
    th Support group
    th
    th
tfoot
tr
    th #
    th Date
    th Issue
    th Author
    th Support group
    th
    th
```

and script for datatable

```
script(type = 'text/javascript').
            $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#reception_issues').DataTable({
            "ajax": "http://localhost:4444/data2.json",
            "columns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<select id='setGroupOfSupport' class='form-control' ng-model = 'selectedGsqroupOfSupport' ng-options = 'group as group.item_name for group in listOfGroupSupport'></select>"
                },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<button ng-click='changeResponsibleGroupOfSupport' class='form-control btn btn-primary'>Change group</button>"
                },
                {
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": "<button ng-click='acceptIssue' class='form-control btn btn-primary'>Accept</button>"
                }
            ]

        });
    });
```

and my test JSON file

```
{
"data": [
    [
        "2346",
        "2015-20-03",
        "Issue 1",
        "Business 1"
    ],
    [
        "2545",
        "2015-20-01",
        "Issue 2",
        "Business 2",
    ],
    [
        "1235",
        "2015-20-02",
        "Issue 3",
        "Business 3"
    ],
    [
        "9800",
        "2015-20-04",
        "Issue 4",
        "Business 4"
    ]
]
}
```

SELECT box should contain a list: Business 1, Business 2, etc.

Can I fill select box using `AngularJS`?
How I can fill select box?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-repeat` and have a look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.opts = [
    [
        "2346",
        "2015-20-03",
        "Issue 1",
        "Business 1"
    ],
    [
        "2545",
        "2015-20-01",
        "Issue 2",
        "Business 2",
    ],
    [
        "1235",
        "2015-20-02",
        "Issue 3",
        "Business 3"
    ],
    [
        "9800",
        "2015-20-04",
        "Issue 4",
        "Business 4"
    ]
  ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="opt in opts">{{opt[3]}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: see how the data array is assigned to `$scope.opts` in my example

Comment: Your question was "Can I fill select box using AngularJS ? How I can fill select box?". What else do you wanna do?

Comment: OK. I'll correct my question: "Can I fill select box using AngularJS into datatable? How I can fill select box into datatable?"

Comment: add `ng-model="myVar"` to the `<select>`. You can access the selected value in your controller.